How to use deferred data incapsulated in the component?
I have simple component (not page, it is separate self-sufficient component) which can be used for both authenticated and anonymous users. Products loading for some time (actually it loads subscriptions, plans, etc) and makes entire page load time awful. I am following recommendation from documentation https://remix.run/docs/en/main/guides/streaming and basically just not works.
First of all vite analyser shows error
'~/services/auth.server' imported by 'app/components/Landing/Products.tsx'

Of course it does as it uses on the server side to get user and load stuff from DB.
Here is simplified code I am using to fetch data for component and which doesn't work.
import { auth } from "~/services/auth.server";

export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
  console.log("[products] loader started", new Date());

  const user = await auth.isAuthenticated(request);

  const products = collections.products.findMany({ userId: user._id });

  return defer({ products })
}


export default function Products() {
  const { products } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();

  return (
      <div className="container">
        <Suspense fallback={<div> LOADING PRODUCTS...</div>}>
          <Await resolve={products}>
            { (products) => <Product product={product} /> }
          </Await>
        </Suspense>
      </div>
  );
}


How to implement data streaming in isolated component correctly?

Exporting a loader function from a file that is not a route file will not work. If you move the loader function into the route file where your <Products> component is used, then the useLoaderData hook should work as expected in the <Products> component.
The way your example is written the loader function will never be called, so useLoaderData() will return null and that will cause a TypeError, because you cannot destructure products from null.
This works:
In your route file (e.g., app/routes/product-listings.tsx)
import type { LoaderFunctionArgs } from '@remix-run/node'
import { auth } from '~/services/auth.server'
import Products from '~/components/Landing/Products'
// import collections from ??????

export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
  const user = await auth.isAuthenticated(request)
  const products = collections.products.findMany({ userId: user._id })
  return defer({ products })
}

export default function ProductListings() {
  return <Products />
}

In your component file (e.g., app/components/Landing/Products.tsx)
import type { loader } from '~/routes/product-listings'
import { Await, useLoaderData } from '@remix-run/react'
import { Suspense } from 'react'
// import Product from ??????

export default function Products() {
  const { products } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>()
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Suspense fallback={<div> LOADING PRODUCTS...</div>}>
        <Await resolve={products}>
          {(products) =>
            products.map((product) => <Product key={product._id} product={product} />)
          }
        </Await>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  )
}


Also you can pass defered products as a prop to Products then use it in . @jason-t-szabo what do you think? Is it eligible?
